# Data access by Static Methods

Tags: c#, java, methods, static, instance-variables

As texts say, Static methods don't access non-static data, so howcome main() method (declared as static) in nearly all programming languages, is able to work on instance members ?

Comment: Got an example of this actually working? As stated, in C# (The language you tagged), what you are describing does not work. Please provide an example to clarify your question.

Comment: using System;

namespace TableOfInteger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) /// STATIC METHOD
        {
            int x, i; // NOT DECLARED STATIC !!
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number whose table you wish to generate : ");
            x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for(i=1; i<11; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, i, (x * i));
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static `Main` method, at least in C# is used to create *instances* of classes used by the application - these instances are used to access their instance variables.

You will see in most applications calls to `new` in the `Main` method. This creates an *instance* of a class that can access instance variables.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by, "The static method, at least in C# is used to create instances of classes used by the application"  What "static method"?

Comment: I agree. But consider the case of the class having Main itself. Its object is never created, so Main is declared as static. In this Main, if i don't mention a member as static (explicitly), i can still use it and everything goes fine. How is that possible ? Are there exceptions to the static rules relating to the Main method ?

Comment: @PrateekKiran - "if i don't mention a member as static (explicitly), i can still use it and everything goes fine" - You can't. I was not able to. The compiler will complain. I can't call instance methods from a static method (unless I instantiate an object and call the methods on the instance). How are you able to compile code that will call instance methods from a static method?

Comment: @Oded -  using System; namespace TableOfInteger { class Program { static void Main(string[] args) ///STATIC METHOD { int x, i; /// NOT DECLARED STATIC Console.WriteLine("Enter the number whose table you wish to generate : "); x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); for(i=1; i<11; i++) { Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, i, (x * i)); } Console.Read(); } } }

Comment: @PrateekKiran - You seem to be talking about the local variables of the method. Those "belong" to the method and are considered thread static.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. That's what i was wanting to know. Those local variables are IMPLICITLY static right ?

Comment: @PrateekKiran - I wouldn't say so. They get instantiated _within_ the method when called (so if you make a second static method instead of your `Main` and call that twice, you will see what I mean).

Answer (score 4):

That is not true as far as Java is concerned, you can only access instance variable after creating an instance of that Class within main.

The moment you create an instance of a class it become method local and not instance, and then you are accessing properties of that object, but inside main method you cannot directly use the instance variable.

for e.g.

```
public class TestStatic1 {
    private int number = 0;

    private static int staticnumber = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        number = 10; // cannot compile at this line.

        staticnumber = 10;
    }
}
```

Another one

```
public class TestStatic1 {
    private int number = 0;

    private static int staticnumber = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestStatic1 static1 = new TestStatic1();
        static1.number = 10; // perfectly fine, accessed via an object.

        staticnumber = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. But that's still inside the main method right ? And main is static. So how come we get to work on the instance variables by the use of objects created in main itself ?

Comment: Once you have an object of a given type, you can call any methods _on that object,_ static or not.

Comment: @PrateekKiran restriction is only on accessing non static properties or methods, when you are accessing properties or method via an object, this is not a direct access, hence the rule doesnt apply.

Comment: @mprabhat 

using System;
namespace TableOfInteger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) ///STATIC METHOD
        {
            int x, i; /// NOT DECLARED STATIC
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number whose table you wish to generate : ");
            x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for(i=1; i<11; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} * {1} = {2}", x, i, (x * i));
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

The Main-Method is a static entry-point.
In Java it mostly looks like this:

```
public class MainClass { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        MainClass m = new MainClass();
        m.DoSomething();
        m.DoSomethingPrivate();

        DoSomethingStatic
    }

    public void DoSomething() {}
    private void DoSomethingPrivate() {}

    public static void DocSomethingStatic() {} 
}
```

It has only direct access to protected or private instance-members.

Answer (score 0):

A `main` method can't access the non-static fields in the class that *holds* `main`. If you provide it with an instance (or create a new instance within the method), it can access those fine. Similar to this:

```
public static void foo(String s) {
    System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: In a static method, if i don't declare any member as static (explicitly) then how is the method able to run ? (With reference to the Main method)

Answer (score 0):

"*Static methods don't access non-static data*" **More precisely** : Static methods don't access non-static **members**.